# Upload Images to Firebase for android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-console

Hello all I am new to android and stackoverflow So sorry in advance for any mistakes

I want to use firebase as a backend server for android application where I want to keep multiple images. 
My question is how to upload multiple images (nearly 100-150) to firebase from the firebase console itself not from android app, so that it can be downloaded through android app.

Answer (score 2):

You can't easily upload many files using the Firebase console.  I suggest you use [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) instead to upload files in bulk.

```
gsutil cp * gs://my-bucket
```

Comment: Is there any tutorial to use this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Firebase Storage:
[image]

Here you can see all the images which you've uploaded.

You can download your images through URLs which you find clicking on each image:
[image]